# Calling ACF from different CPT via slug

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am wanting to echo a custom field created in a CTP to a widget.

I would usually use something like the below to call a field from a page ID, but as my CTP uses a slug rather than ID i'm looking for suggestions on how to do this.

```
<?php
$other_page = 173;
?>

<?php the_field('shop_content_box', $other_page); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, any CPT has its own slug. The same way non-custom post types (such as Posts, Pages or Attachments) have theirs (being respectively `post`, `page` and `attachment`).

But be careful not to confuse a *Custom Post **Type*** with an actual post of that type. Any post in Wordpress (including, of course, those of a CPT), has an ID. If you want to query a Custom Field value with ACF's `get_field` or `the_field` of any other post/page **you must** use the ID, as in your example:

```
<?php the_field('shop_content_box', $other_page); ?>
```

So, if you only know the `$other_page_slug` *(I wonder how do you get the slug alone...)* you should retrieve its Post Object. See: [Get a post by its slug](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#comment-1194).

```
<?php
function the_field_by_slug( $field, $slug, $cpt = 'post' ) {
    $args = [
        'name'           => $slug,
        'post_type'      => $cpt,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ];
    $my_post = get_posts( $args );
    if( $my_post ) {
        the_field( $field, $my_post->ID );
    }
}
the_field_by_slug( 'shop_content_box', $other_post_slug, $custom_post_type_slug );
?>
```